# Grouping a dataframe by defined dates

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I'm trying to simply sum the values between each specific set of dates that I have defined. I'm running into trouble as this isn't calendar year data, rather fiscal year. Looking to sum the values between the fiscal quarters. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

#sample dataframe
begin_date = '2017-01-01'
values = [*range(2100)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': values,
                  'dates':pd.date_range(begin_date, periods=len(values))})

df


#defined dates
F2Q17 =  date(2017, 4, 1)
F3Q17 =  date(2017, 7, 1)
F4Q17 =  date(2017, 9, 30)
F1Q18 =  date(2017, 12, 30)
F2Q18 =  date(2018, 3, 31)
F3Q18 =  date(2018, 6, 30)
F4Q18 =  date(2018, 9, 29)
F1Q19 =  date(2018, 12, 29)
F2Q19 =  date(2019, 3, 30)
F3Q19 =  date(2019, 6, 29)
F4Q19 =  date(2019, 9, 28)
F1Q20 =  date(2019, 12, 28)
F2Q20 =  date(2020, 3, 28)
F3Q20 =  date(2020, 6, 27)
F4Q20 =  date(2020, 9, 26)
F1Q21 =  date(2020, 12, 26)
F2Q21 =  date(2021, 3, 27)
F3Q21 =  date(2021, 6, 26)
F4Q21 =  date(2021, 9, 25)
F1Q22 =  date(2021, 12, 25)
F2Q22 =  date(2022, 3, 26)
F3Q22 =  date(2022, 6, 25)
F4Q22 = date(2022, 9, 25)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
group_dates = [date(2017, 4, 1),
date(2017, 7, 1),
date(2017, 9, 30),
date(2017, 12, 30),
date(2018, 3, 31),
date(2018, 6, 30),
date(2018, 9, 29),
date(2018, 12, 29),
date(2019, 3, 30),
date(2019, 6, 29),
date(2019, 9, 28),
date(2019, 12, 28),
date(2020, 3, 28),
date(2020, 6, 27),
date(2020, 9, 26),
date(2020, 12, 26),
date(2021, 3, 27),
date(2021, 6, 26),
date(2021, 9, 25),
date(2021, 12, 25),
date(2022, 3, 26),
date(2022, 6, 25),
date(2022, 9, 25)]

df_groups = pd.DataFrame({"dates":pd.to_datetime(group_dates), "group":pd.to_datetime(group_dates)})

(
    pd.merge(df, df_groups, on="dates", how="left")
    .assign(group=lambda x: x.group.bfill())
    .groupby("group")
    [["values"]].sum()
    .reset_index()
)
```

**Output**:

```
    group       values
0   2017-04-01  4095
1   2017-07-01  12376
2   2017-09-30  20657
3   2017-12-30  28938
4   2018-03-31  37219
5   2018-06-30  45500
6   2018-09-29  53781
7   2018-12-29  62062
8   2019-03-30  70343
9   2019-06-29  78624
10  2019-09-28  86905
11  2019-12-28  95186
12  2020-03-28  103467
13  2020-06-27  111748
14  2020-09-26  120029
15  2020-12-26  128310
16  2021-03-27  136591
17  2021-06-26  144872
18  2021-09-25  153153
19  2021-12-25  161434
20  2022-03-26  169715
21  2022-06-25  177996
22  2022-09-25  188370
```

Comment: Thanks! this output looks like what I'm after. quick question, what would df2 be defined as here? it is just an empty dataframe?

Comment: Oh, sorry. There was an mistake. Just fixed it. Now with lambda instead of df2. Does it work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
# put the required dates inside a list:

dates = [
    date(2017, 4, 1),
    date(2017, 7, 1),
    date(2017, 9, 30),
    date(2017, 12, 30),
    date(2018, 3, 31),
    date(2018, 6, 30),
    date(2018, 9, 29),
    date(2018, 12, 29),
    date(2019, 3, 30),
    date(2019, 6, 29),
    date(2019, 9, 28),
    date(2019, 12, 28),
    date(2020, 3, 28),
    date(2020, 6, 27),
    date(2020, 9, 26),
    date(2020, 12, 26),
    date(2021, 3, 27),
    date(2021, 6, 26),
    date(2021, 9, 25),
    date(2021, 12, 25),
    date(2022, 3, 26),
    date(2022, 6, 25),
    date(2022, 9, 25),
]

# create a series by which we group the dataframe:
m = df["dates"].isin(dates).cumsum()

# group the dataframe, print some info:
for _, g in df.groupby(m):
    print(f'Group {g["dates"].min().date()} - {g["dates"].max().date()}')

    # uncomment to print whole group:
    # print(g)
```

Prints:

```
Group 2017-01-01 - 2017-03-31
Group 2017-04-01 - 2017-06-30
Group 2017-07-01 - 2017-09-29
Group 2017-09-30 - 2017-12-29
Group 2017-12-30 - 2018-03-30
Group 2018-03-31 - 2018-06-29
Group 2018-06-30 - 2018-09-28
Group 2018-09-29 - 2018-12-28
Group 2018-12-29 - 2019-03-29
Group 2019-03-30 - 2019-06-28
Group 2019-06-29 - 2019-09-27
Group 2019-09-28 - 2019-12-27
Group 2019-12-28 - 2020-03-27
Group 2020-03-28 - 2020-06-26
Group 2020-06-27 - 2020-09-25
Group 2020-09-26 - 2020-12-25
Group 2020-12-26 - 2021-03-26
Group 2021-03-27 - 2021-06-25
Group 2021-06-26 - 2021-09-24
Group 2021-09-25 - 2021-12-24
Group 2021-12-25 - 2022-03-25
Group 2022-03-26 - 2022-06-24
Group 2022-06-25 - 2022-09-24
Group 2022-09-25 - 2022-10-01
```